# Is it save to ignore *pbx* files in version control of xcode project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, git

I want to upload my xcode project to git, but only needed files. I see different files that i'm sure are created during build, but about others i'm not. I'm talking about `*pbx*` and `*.oa` files.

I'm using git. And want to configure an "exclude" file with patterns of files to be ignored. Is it safe to add the following patterns: `*pbx*` and `*.oa`?

Maybe someone can share an exclude file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not safe for pbx because project.pbxproject is very important (and a real pain with version control). I am unsure about *.oa but here is a list of items I currently exclude in svn.

```
*.pbxuser,
*.mode*,
build,
.DS_Store,
*.perspectivev*,
*.xcworkspace,
xcuserdata
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Git, I use the following `.gitignore` file:

```
.DS_Store
build/
*.xcodeproj/*
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

That's for Xcode 3.x. There may be additional files generated by Xcode 4 that should be ignored (maybe someone else will kindly provide that information).

Comment: A one liner with mostly that: `printf "*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge" > .gitattributes && printf ".DS_Store\n*.xcodeproj/*\n!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" > .gitignore`